# Batch file Copy of specific files/shortcuts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to copy 3 specific files from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office` to a new location of `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`

However i am only trying to copy 3 specific files from this location.

> File 1: Microsoft Excel 2010
>
> File 2: Microsoft Outlook 2010
>
> File 3: Microsoft Word 2010

Thank you in advance, hopefully i have been clear.

Answer (score 1):

How about just copying it?

```
copy /y "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Excel 2010" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
copy /y "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Outlook 2010" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
copy /y "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Word 2010" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
```

or in a for loop:

```
@echo off
set "pth=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\"
for %%i in ("%pth%Microsoft Word 2010" "%pth%Microsoft Excel 2010" "%pth%Microsoft Outlook 2010") do copy /Y %%i "C:\Users\Public\Desktop"
```